# Looking for clr/cli code where a structure is returned from c# method to win32 vc++ dll

Tags: c#-4.0, clr, coreclr

I am looking for source code or links to source code example where a structure is passed as a parameter from a win32 dll to a c# method, and that same c# method returns a dll.
The win32 is a clr project (safe clr) and the c# project is class library dll. Any links to source code examples or source code itself would help.
Please no comments are suggestion, just source code that work,